# Architecture: Double views on the backend & frontend

Tags: php, view, angularjs

I am building a webapp which uses AngularJS (or another JS MVC fw) and has its own templating language. At the same time, my back-end also has a template language, twig. I'm finding myself only having a general template/view in the backend and then doing everything with Angular... Does this mean my backend is too complicated/ I need something else?

Note that I do need user authentication..

Comment: If it's working for you than it's not too complicated. Not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Nothing wrong with using twig to setup the base for using angular, although it does add overhead.

Comment: Overhead is actually what I was afraid for although I don't know what this can practically mean.. Performance cost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your back-end rendering doesn't mix HTML with your data, back-end rendering is very useful. In our application we turn on/off functionality depending you licenses/permissions/etc, so we render different front-end templates depending on that. That makes our front-end code simpler since it has less things to deal with.

Let's say you have a list of tasks to display. You would handle the rendering of the task data on the client, but you might want to determine which columns that should be displayed on the server. Something like this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <?php foreach ($columns as $column) { ?>
            <th><?php echo $column->name; ?></th>
        <?php } ?>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="task in tasks">
        <?php foreach ($columns as $column) { ?>
            <td>{{<?php echo $column->property; ?>}}</td>
        <?php } ?>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

As longs as the templates your back-end is rendering are cacheable on the client, I'd say your fine.

Comment: That's a very nice answer, so you're having a finer control of data and you help your front-end by limiting the amount of data it has to deal with.. Although one could say that you can use your back-end Controller to do this kind of filtering and not the views/templates..